# Custom validation that boolean field has a boolean and not any other type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, my model and validation is this:

```
class Suya < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor

  validates :meat, presence: true
  validates_inclusion_of :spicy, :in => [true, false]
end
```

The problem is that when I run this test:

```
test "suya is invalid if spiciness is not a boolean" do
    suya = Suya.new(meat: "beef", spicy: 1)
    suya1 = Suya.new(meat: "beef", spicy: "some string")

    assert suya.invalid?
    refute suya1.valid?
  end
```

I get a deprecation warning that says:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: You attempted to assign a value which is not
>   explicitly `true` or `false` to a boolean column. Currently this value
>   casts to `false`. This will change to match Ruby's semantics, and will
>   cast to `true` in Rails 5.

So I think my validation is not doing what I think it should be doing. I think my validation checks the presence of the column value and if it IS or is converted to true or false. So I think my test fixtures both convert to false and therefore pass the test which I don't want. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Rails performs type casting any time you assign a value to an attribute. This is a convenience thing. It's not really your text case's fault, it's just how Rails works. If the attribute is a Boolean it'll convert truthy-looking values (`true`, `1`, `'1'`, `'t'`, `'T'`, `'true'`, `'TRUE'`, `'on'`, `'ON'`) to `true` and anything else to `false`. For example:

```
suya.spicy = "asdf"
suya.spicy # => false

# Likewise for other attribute types:
# Assuming Suya has an `id` attribute that is an Integer
suya.id = "asdf"
suya.id # => 0  # Because "asdf".to_i # => 0

# Assuming Suya has a `name` attribute that is a String
suya.name = 1
suya.name # => "1"  # Because 1.to_s # => "1"
```

So this is just how rails works. In your test case your values are being typecast into their respective attributes' types via mass-assignment.

You can either test out Rails's typecasting by assigning "some value" to your booleans or you can just use more obvious boolean values like `true` and `false` in your test cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom validation like:

```
validate :check_boolean_field

def check_boolean_field
  false unless self.spicy.is_a?(Boolean)
end
```

Comment: There is no `Boolean` in Ruby.